# Kindle Fire HD: movies are brighter than jpgs

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer, kindle-fire, brightness

I've been working on an app where the user touches the screen to start a movie. The screen image is the first frame of the movie. Once the touch happens, the movie plays. I do this by putting a jpg of the first frame in front of the movie, and then removing the jpg once I think the movie is playing. (Figuring out when that happens is impossible, but that's another issue. And on older devices if you remove the image too soon, you get black.)

Tested this on probably six different devices. Today the seventh: Kindle Fire HD. On this device, the movies are all brighter than the corresponding jpgs. On all other devices, they match perfectly. Any ideas what could cause this or how to fix?

(Another issue with the HD is that movies take a REALLY long time to start playing. But that's another issue.)

EDIT: here is my main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/vv" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

and here is code:

```
public class VideoTestActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, OnPreparedListener, OnCompletionListener {
private VideoView vv;
private ImageView iv;
private Bitmap b;
private MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
private static final String TAG = VideoTestActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private volatile boolean prepared = false;
private volatile boolean readytoplay = false;
private volatile boolean playing = false;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv);
    iv.bringToFront();
    vv = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.vv);
    b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.babyblack);
    iv.setBackgroundColor( 0xFFDFA679 );
    vv.getHolder().addCallback(this);
    mp.setOnPreparedListener( this );
    mp.setOnCompletionListener( this );
    try {
        mp.setDataSource( this, Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.ape) );
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        Log.d(TAG,"illegal argument exception on set data source");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        Log.d(TAG,"security exception on set data source");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.d(TAG,"illegal state exception on set data source");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG,"IO exception on set data source");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float dx, dy;
    Log.d(TAG,"touch event");
    if ( !playing && event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ) {
        Log.d(TAG,"action up");
        if ( prepared ) {
            playing = true;
            Log.d(TAG,"hardware accelerated: iv="+iv.isHardwareAccelerated()+", vv="+vv.isHardwareAccelerated());
            mp.start();
            Log.d(TAG, "playing video in onTouch callback");
            Log.d(TAG,"hardware accelerated: iv="+iv.isHardwareAccelerated()+", vv="+vv.isHardwareAccelerated());
        } else
            readytoplay = true;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d(TAG,"surface is created");
    mp.setDisplay( vv.getHolder() );
    try {
        mp.prepareAsync();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        Log.d(TAG,"illegal argument exception on prepare");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        Log.d(TAG,"security exception on prepare");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.d(TAG,"illegal state exception on prepare");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    Log.d(TAG,"video is prepared");
    prepared = true;
    if ( readytoplay ) {
        playing = true;
        mp.start();
        iv.setVisibility( View.GONE );
        Log.d(TAG,"playing video from prepared callback");
    }
}

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
    Log.d(TAG,"video is done");
    playing = false;
    iv.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
}}
```

I changed the ImageView to have no image, but just a solid-colored background. The only data file you need is an mp4 movie. When you touch the screen, the movie plays, hidden behind the ImageView. The screen immediately brightens when I touch it (mp.start() happens), then the movie starts playing, and it gradually dims a bit, then brightens again, and finally stabilizes when the movie is done.

I tried hardware acceleration, and no hardware acceleration; no difference. I tried plugging the Kindle Fire HD in, and not plugging it in; no difference.

I would post the 2-second mp4 file that I am using but don't know how.

Comment: do you have a sample you could share that shows this? I've not seen this problem using an embedded html5 video with a poster to fake the same but I've not tried with a videoView and an overlaid image. Wondering if it's the overlay that's causing an artifact.. have you tried overlaying the image on just half the video (to see if there's a difference between where it was vs where it wasn't)?

Comment: @Offbeatmammal - Just tried that and no. The entire screen brightens as soon as mp.start() is called and dims when the movie is done. Even if you can't see the movie (because it is hidden by a jpg), the screen brightens. So it looks like the screen brightness parameter is being adjusted, but I turned brightness all the way up and it still happens. Very puzzling; will continue to experiment. And yes, sample code would be nice if I can get my act together.

Comment: Is it possible that this has to do with hardware acceleration? Trying to test this hypothesis but don't know how. It's as if starting the movie player changes the way the screen is rendered (including parts of the screen that have nothing to do with the movie player).

Comment: (Just to be clear: I made the view with the jpg be half the screen, I made the surfaceview with the movie be half the screen, etc.; each time doing mp.start() brightened the whole screen.)

Comment: I just posted code for case where image stays in front of movie the whole time. Another feature of this is that when the movie ends I can sort of see a redraw happening, which for some reason involves a faint dark line down the center of the screen just for an instant.

Comment: Do you have Automatic brightness on, or manually set? I do see a slight difference in brightness with surrounding elements on mine when it is in automatic. there also seems to be a change in brightness when the on-screen controls appear/disappear

Comment: @Offbeatmammal - My last report (bright at start of movie, then dimmer, then brighter at the end) (felt a little like the movie was like a power saw messing with the brightness of lightbulbs) was apparently due to machine getting in weird state. After a restart, it simplified: it just gets a little brighter when you start the movie, then dims back to original brightness at the end. Plus there is that weird redraw at the end with briefly appearing line across the center in the long direction. This happens whether automatic brightness is on or off (it's dimmer with automatic brightness on).

Comment: I have no on-screen controls. The image color that I picked makes this show up well. Tried other colors where it is harder to see.

Comment: could you post the source (or a small sample, but complete project) somewhere ... I've had a quick try on my FireHD 7" and can't see any real difference in brightness but it may be content I'm using or how I'm triggering the display

Answer (score 0):

look like it's by design, per this forum post - https://forums.developer.amazon.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=450#1780